# PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> setResultCallback Delay

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api, android-pendingintent

I have created an application wherein a list of Places are saved in the Database. I only saved the place IDs of the saved Places as per Google documentation.

I then created an interface for the user to enter their current location (mCurrentLocation).

I then created an Asynctask to go thru each of the place IDs saved in the database and check which of the places are within 500meters of the user's location. This is done in doInBackground. As per Google documentation I used getPlaceById and setResultCallback

In the postExecute the Recycler view is updated.

ISSUE: The PendingResult setResultCallback seems to be having a delays. As per my logs, the PostExecute is being called already while the setResultCallback is not yet finished! As a result, my Recycler view is not seeing all the results

LOGS:

Inside for Loop

Inside for Loop

Inside for Loop

for loop exited

onPostExecute entered

Inside for Loop

Inside for Loop

@Override
protected List doInBackground(List... lists) {

```
        ArrayList<Places> selectedPlaces = new ArrayList<>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < lists[0].size(); i++) {


            // Get the place from the placeID
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.
                    getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, lists[0].get(i).getAddress());

            placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Inside for loop");

                    // Get the latitude and longitude for the specific place
                    LatLng latLng = places.get(0).getLatLng();

                    // Set the location object for the specific place
                    Location A = new Location("Place");
                    A.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
                    A.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

                    // get the distance of the place from the selected location
                    float distance = A.distanceTo(mUserLocation);

                    // if the distance is less than 500m
                    if (distance < 500) {
                        selectedPlaces.add(lists[0].get(position));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "for loop exited");
        return selectedPlaces;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Places> places) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPostExecute entered");
        //update Recycler view

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code. Instead of using setResultCallback I should be using await() instead.

so the new code should be this:

```
PlaceBuffer places = placeResult.await();
```

then remove

```
placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
```